# C# web browser accessing a web page containing .js after it has run its scripts

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have a C# application (180K lines) to access web pages from a site. It captures information from these web pages, makes decisions, and then submits for actions at the same site. This worked fine with mostly static Html pages. The site has now redesigned its pages with quite a bit of JavaScript and jQuery.

I use:

```
HtmlDocument WebPage1 = MainWebBrowser.Document;
```

after testing with:

```
if (MainWebBrowser.ReadyState.ToString() == "Complete")
```

The document obtained this way does not seem to have its Html elements updated.

On the other hand the same page displayed in the C# code's web browser window (in Visual Studio) has the updated Html elements (I can submit for actions manually from the page).

I can see what the updated Html elements ought to look like from F12 on Microsoft Edge with its URL pointing to the same pages.

**The question is:** how can I have my C# capture the HtmlDocument that has been updated by all scripts on the Html page? This way I can programmatically get information and submit for actions at the site.

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015.

Comment: Maybe htmlagilitypack? Do you want to parse website?

Comment: You'd have to poll for a known piece of text to be present before you declare it ready.

Comment: I think that the javascript isn't executing at all and that's why you don't see the changes. I don't know what MainWebBrowser class is, but i would guess that could be capable to execute javascript if is a "real" webbrowser.

Comment: Since it sounds like you're performing some sort of browser automation, perhaps it'd be beneficial in looking into [Selenium WebDriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver), which makes accessing and using a website through code pretty easy. If you're familiar with CSS selectors, Selenium makes it easy to use this paradigm to reference elements on a document.

Comment: Jeff, thanks! Implementing your comment worked: "polling for a known piece of html element".